# How to use Cocos 2D 1.1.0, When I run a sample Cocos2D Appication it gives error

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios4

How to use Cocos2D 1.1.0, When I am choose a template as Cocos2D Application and name it "NewCocos", When simply run this project without doing anything It gives me

- 124 errors

  of same type = **error: missing binary operator before token "("**

this errors shows near "#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(objc_arc)"

- 18 Warnings

  of same type = **warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic**

this warning shows near "#pragma clang diagnostic push" , "#pragma clang diagnostic pop" etc...

I am using XCode 3.2.4 and iOS / iPhone OS 4.1

In short statement gives (124 times) error of

error: missing binary operator before token "("

on the statement without quotes "#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(objc_arc)"

This is working fine in Cocos v1.0.1 older version but not working on cocos v1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2D v1.1 requires to set the compiler to "Apple LLVM compiler" in Build Settings. Only Xcode 4.0 and newer are shipped with the Apple LLVM compiler. Furthermore, to enable ARC you must be using at least Xcode 4.2 with the "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0".

You should seriously consider upgrading. Xcode 3.2 is over 2 years old now (released: August 2009). [As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915477/iphone-app-submission-software-requirements), only apps built with the latest, or if not "too old" the second to latest iOS SDK version are going to be approved by Apple (at the time of this writing iOS 5.0 is the latest SDK but iOS 4.3 apps are also still accepted). Regardless of that, Xcode 4 makes it a lot easier to submit apps through its built-in Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

this is XCode 3.2.4 problem Update Your X-Code Minimum X-Code 4.2.0